# why does wordpress have three(?) empty index.php files?

Tags: wordpress

I just installed wordpress and am curious as to why my front page is located at localhost/wordpress and also why another page i've created seems to exist only in the database? why are these index.php files blank? Where would one go to add javscript, php scripts or drop in another library? Is there an article that explains how this is set up? What functions I should be aware of? thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/First_Steps_With_WordPress

Comment: i guess i"d like an answer that pointed me to a specific filename?

Comment: to edit the front page make the changes in index.php that is located in side your theme folder wp-content/themes/themes/%ThemeName%